# What is this menubar icon with NW-SE double-headed arrow?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

What is this menubar icon? I don't remember seeing it before, and it doesn't seem to offer any explanation of what it is.

[image: menubar icon with NW-SE double-headed arrow]

The inverted triangle (▼) in the upper left doesn't do anything when clicked. Typing in the [Search] box only changes [All Programs ▶] to [◀ Back].

Comment: That's an app you have installed. If you mouse over the icon (while it's not expanded) and wait a second, a dialog of which app it is from should appear.

Comment: @owlswipe That doesn't work for this particular icon, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's *VMware Fusion Start Menu*.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can go into VMWare's settings and disable it if you'd like.